# NSMenuItem's value binding with BOOL

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, appkit

I am having some issues binding an NSMenuItem's "value" binding to a BOOL.

I simplified the problem to this:

1) The menu item *must* call the action method that changes the value of the BOOL otherwise it doesn't work (i.e. if an NSButton calls a method that changes the value of the BOOL then the menu item won't update)

2) Even if the action method makes the BOOL a constant (i.e. `enabled = YES`), the "value" of the menu item still alternates.

Any ideas? I'm so confused!

Here is the code:

**MenuBindings_AppDelegate.h**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface Menu_BindingsAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> 
{   
   BOOL foo;
}

- (IBAction)toggle:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)makeYes:(id)sender;

@property BOOL foo;

@end
```

**Menu_BindingsAppDelegate.m**

```
@implementation Menu_BindingsAppDelegate

@synthesize foo;

- (IBAction)toggle:(id)sender
{
   [self setFoo:!foo];
}

- (IBAction)makeYes:(id)sender
{   
   [self setFoo:YES];
}

@end
```

In my nib, I have a button connected to the -makeYes: action and a menu item connected to the -toggle: action. The menu item's "value" binding is bound to the app delegate's "foo" attribute.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cocoa Bindings uses *[Key-Value Observing](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving)* (KVO) to obtain notification of changes in model objects. In order for the change in the model (your `BOOL` value) to be noticed by observers including any views that use bindings, you must update the model using *[Key-Value Coding](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding)*-compliant accessor methods. If you just set the value of the ivar directly, no KVO notifications will be sent.

You can either implement the KVC accessors yourself or declare a property and use the `@synthesize` keyword in your implementation to have the compiler create compliant accessors for you.

This is how you would implement KVC-compliant accessors:

```
//YourModel.h
@interface YourModel : NSObject
{
    BOOL enabled;
}
- (BOOL)enabled;
- (void)setEnabled:(BOOL)flag;
@end

//YourModel.m
@implementation YourModel
- (BOOL)enabled
{
    return enabled;
}
- (void)setEnabled:(BOOL)flag
{
    enabled = flag;
}
@end
```

and this is how you would do the same thing using Objective-C 2.0 property syntax:

```
//YourModel.h
@interface YourModel : NSObject
{
    BOOL enabled;
}
@property BOOL enabled;
@end

//YourModel.m
@implementation YourModel
@synthesize enabled;
@end
```

You can then call `[yourModel setEnabled:YES]` and any registered KVO observers (including your menu binding) will be informed of the change.

Alternatively, you can call `yourModel.enabled = YES` which will use the proper KVC accessors if available.

I uploaded a [sample project](http://github.com/rkeniger/MenuItemBool) to demonstrate how it's done.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried using both willChangeValueForKey:/didChangeValueForKey: and using @property/@synthesize behavior, but I'm still getting odd results...

Comment: Can you post your code? You don't need to use will/didChangeValueForKey: if you are implementing KVC-compliant accessors.

Comment: Never mind, I figured out the problem. When you click on the menu item, its value automatically gets toggled. Didn't realize that...thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's because the binding is two-way. I can understand why that could be confusing.